# Unable to create a conference on UberConference via Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-calendar-api, calendly

I am trying to create a conference on Uberconference by using their Chrome Extension. It adds an entry to Google Calendar but doesn't create the conference on Uberconference. When I refresh the Upcoming Events tab then it shows nothing.

Here are the steps which I have followed:

**STEP1:** **Chrome Extension:**

[image]

**STEP2:** **Conference Scheduler (Google Calendar):**

[image]

**STEP3:** **Entry added in Calendar:**

[image]

**STEP4:** **Missing on Uberconference:**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related

Comment: Since this question is off-topic anyway, it's a good opportunity for some meta-advice. I notice that your questions need a fair bit of editing, and I wonder if you could note the following? (a) when referring to yourself "I", it is always a capital letter, no exceptions. (b) everyone "tries their best to explain", but there is no value in adding that explicitly, (c) there's no need to add "please help me" religiously to all of your questions. Readers know you need help, so adding this may be understood as a form of pleading. Keep it succinct if you can!

Comment: I'm trying to put this on hold again @DaImTo - would you cast a vote?